# Remove chars/strings in a string

Tags: php

I have a string which called $team1 which contain a name of team 1. However a team can contain several strings like .CS, Dota2 and so on. How can i make a array or something like of these strings which it should remove from the $team1 string?

Comment: Give example by code.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, so that we know exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all occurences defined in array `$ar` with empty string:

```
$ar = array('string1','string2',...);
$string_new = str_replace($ar,'',$string_old);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array.

```
$team1 = "Dota,CS,ELSE";
$teamArray = explode(",", $team1);
unset($teamArray[1]);
echo implode(",", $team1); //output "Dota,ELSE"
```